# How to apply Getter/Setter method for private variable in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, setter, getter

The purpose of this program is to access the private variable jtextfield from another class. I created this simple program that takes user input from a JTextField. I have getter and setter methods in one class and the button and field in another class. Therefore, I want to print something when the user types something in the textfield. But when the button is clicked, the program does not print and gives an error:

Error: javax.swing.JTextField[,140,62,124x20,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI

Have I initialized the getter and setter methods correctly?

Example1:

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Example1 {

private JTextField Name;


public Example1(){

 Name = null;

 }

public Example1(JTextField n){

 Name = n;

 } 


public void setName(JTextField Name) {
    this.Name = Name; 
}
public JTextField getName() {
    return Name;
}
```

}

Example2:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


 public class Example2
{

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

private JTextField Name = new JTextField();
private JButton Button = new JButton("Print");


public Example2(){

panel.setLayout(null);  

Name.setBounds(140, 62, 124, 20);
Button.setBounds(320, 62, 133, 20); 

panel.add(Name);  
panel.add(Button);  

frame.add(panel);
frame.setSize(470,310);
frame.setVisible(true);



Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

add(Name);

}
});



}


public static void add(JTextField Name){

Example1 x = new Example1();
x.setName(Name);

JTextField a = x.getName();
System.out.println(a);

}


public static void main(String [] args){

    Example2 print = new Example2();
}



}
```

Comment: As a side note, the standard in Java is to use `lowerCamelCase` for member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to print the element itself you want to access the string hold by the textfield. It's not an error. It just calls toString() method for the JTextField.

Use `textfield.getText()` to access the value of the Textfield. In Example2 this would be:

```
public static void add(JTextField Name){
    Example1 x = new Example1();
    x.setName(Name);

    JTextField a = x.getName();
    System.out.println(a.getText());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok i tried that and it worked. Also, how can i add the jtextfield to an arraylist and use a loop to print out the value?

Comment: List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
 textFields.add(Name);
  
 for(int i = 0;i< textFields.size(); i++){
 Name[i] = textFields.get(i).getValue();
 System.out.println(Name[i]);
 
 }

Comment: I always do like this: List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<>(); textFields.add(Name); for (JTextField field : textFields) { System.out.println(field.get(i).getText()); } But your solution should work too. May I ask you to accept this answer?

Comment: OK thanks. Well, my solution gives me an error on Name[i] = textFields.get(i).getValue();

Comment: oh I have overseen this in your code in the comment - there is no getValue() function ...

Comment: I tried fields[i] = textFields.get(i); Name[i] = textFields.get(i).getValue(); and field [i] = textFields.get(i); But non working.

Comment: cause the function is called getText() ... you are still using getValue()  :|

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing isn't an error.  It's the result of printing an object that doesn't have a `toString()` method defined.

```
JTextField a = x.getName();
System.out.println(a);
```

When you pass an object to `System.out.println()` then that objects `toString()` is called.  Since there is no `toString()` for JTextField, the standard `Object.toString()` method is called.

A better way would be:

```
System.out.println(a.getText());
```

Comment: `JTextField` doesn't have a `toString()` method, no, but it's inheriting it from something other than `Object` in this case.  Still, this _is_ the cause of the issue (and a good solution).